# How to append one div container with another div container using appendChild() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've designed a simple HTML form. I'm trying to display card information dynamically on the same page by getting the user's entered data in JavaScript. I'm having trouble while calling the function I created to be invoked upon pressing the Submit button. The function is invoked correctly for the first time but as soon as the user enters 2nd information and clicks on the Submit button, the function is invoked and it overlaps the 1st card... Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<form action="" id="enrol">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Enrol</h1>
            <p>Please fill in this form to get enrolled.</p> <hr />

            <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" required>

            <label for="img"><b>Image</b></label>
            <input type="file" id="img" name="image" required/>

            <label for="dsc"><b>Description</b></label>
            <input id="dsc" type="text" placeholder="Describe yourself in a few lines" name="dsc" required>

            <button id="btn" type="button" class="registerbtn" onclick="showCard(); reset();">Submit</button> <hr/>
          </div>
</form>
```

**Here is the JavaScript:**

```
//Showing Card
function showCard() {
    //get values
    var name, desc, pic;
    name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    desc = document.getElementById("dsc").value;
    pic = document.getElementById("img").files[0].name;

    //create image object
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.setAttribute("width", "auto");
    img.setAttribute("height", "125");
    img.setAttribute("src", "img/" + pic);

    //create layout
    var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
    mainDiv.id = "main";
    mainDiv.className = "container";
    document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "row";
    div.className = "row";
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);

    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.id = "class";
    div2.className = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12";
    div2.innerHTML = "<label><b>Member # 1</b></label> <i>(Your card will look like this)</i>" + "<br />" + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("row").appendChild(div2);

    var div3 = document.createElement("div");
    div3.id = "card";
    div3.className = "card";
    document.getElementById("class").appendChild(div3);

    var div4 = document.createElement("div");
    div4.id = "cardBody";
    div4.className = "cardBody";
    document.getElementById("card").appendChild(div4);

    var div5 = document.createElement("div");
    div5.id = "row1";
    div5.className = "row";
    document.getElementById("cardBody").appendChild(div5);

    var div6 = document.createElement("div");
    div6.id = "class";
    div6.className = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12";
    div6.appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById("row1").appendChild(div6);

    var div7 = document.createElement("div");
    div7.id = "class1";
    div7.className = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12";
    div7.innerHTML = "<h4><b>" + name + "</b></h4>" + "<p>" + desc + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("row1").appendChild(div7);

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.className = "btn-success";
    button.innerHTML = "View Details";
    document.getElementById("class1").appendChild(button);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that your code is still referencing the divs from the first card. So any new card will be appended to the old card. For this you could add a global counter here and add dynamically IDs for the divs. Then the new card will be added for the new divs like this:

```
var counter= 0;

function showCard() {
counter++;
    //get values
    var name, desc, pic;
    name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    desc = document.getElementById("dsc").value;
    pic = document.getElementById("img").files[0].name;

    //create image object
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.setAttribute("width", "auto");
    img.setAttribute("height", "125");
    img.setAttribute("src", "img/" + pic);

    //create layout
    var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
    mainDiv.id = "main"+ counter;
    mainDiv.className = "container";
    document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "row"+ counter;
    div.className = "row";
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);

    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.id = "class"+ counter;
    div2.className = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12";
    div2.innerHTML = "<label><b>Member # 1</b></label> <i>(Your card will look like this)</i>" + "<br />" + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("row").appendChild(div2);

    var div3 = document.createElement("div");
    div3.id = "card"+ counter;
    div3.className = "card";
    document.getElementById("class").appendChild(div3);

    var div4 = document.createElement("div");
    div4.id = "cardBody"+ counter;
    div4.className = "cardBody";
    document.getElementById("card").appendChild(div4);

    var div5 = document.createElement("div");
    div5.id = "row1"+ counter;
    div5.className = "row";
    document.getElementById("cardBody").appendChild(div5);

    var div6 = document.createElement("div");
    div6.id = "class"+ counter;
    div6.className = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12";
    div6.appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById("row1").appendChild(div6);

    var div7 = document.createElement("div");
    div7.id = "class1"+ counter;
    div7.className = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12";
    div7.innerHTML = "<h4><b>" + name + "</b></h4>" + "<p>" + desc + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("row1").appendChild(div7);

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.className = "btn-success";
    button.innerHTML = "View Details";
    document.getElementById("class1").appendChild(button);

}
```

Comment: what happened exactly?

Comment: Nothing happened on clicking the Submit button even for the first time...

Comment: `function reset(){
 document.getElementById("enrol").reset();
}`

Comment: very strange it should be correct and the error message says not that much..